# How to get field collection values from user object?

Tags: 8, users, entities

I added a field collection to the user 'manage field' page, the field machine name is 'houses'. The user may add as many home he want.

This field collection regroup :

- a sample text plain field (the name of the house), the machine name
  "house_name"
- a sample integer field (the size of the house), the
  machine name "house_size"

In a custom module, I want load the current user and get values of all values of all his houses (in an array ?), how can I do that ?

I tried this :

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$user_houses = $user->get('field_houses')->getValue();
ksm($user_houses);
```

But I get :

[image]

It's ok, I set 8 houses in "user edit" page, so I get an array of 8 entries. But, I would like get all data in an array like this :

```
house 1 : name1 : size1
house 2 : name2 : size2
...
house 8 : name8 : size8
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find =)

With :

```
use Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem;
...
$test = FieldCollectionItem::load(3);
```

Where "3" is, by example, a value returned by $user->get('field_houses')->getValue();